# Bootstrap CSS usage of id tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make this code only work if id equals to myCarousel ? Im using bootstrap by the way.

I tried adding #myCarousel tag, but it didnt work.

```
.carousel {
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 675px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
  height: 350px;
}

.carousel .item {
  height: 675px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 675px;
}
```

Comment: `#myCarousel.carousel` for example didn't work?

Comment: Would u mind posting the new css ?

Comment: Done! :) Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the carousel has both the id `myCarousel` and the class `carousel` you can just combine them without any space between them:

```
#myCarousel.carousel {
  ...
}

#myCarousel.carousel-caption {
  ...
}

#myCarousel.carousel .item {
  ...
}
#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .item > img {
  ...
}
```

For the last one (`.carousel-inner`) I assumed it's a child of `#myCarousel`, so there's a space between them.

For more information about this see https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Comment: The correct usage of the last line was yours, thank u

Comment: Well, would u mind helping me with this code too ? It doesent work.  http://pastebin.com/Uwnk21G2

Comment: If you have a new question, please post a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask And please describe your problem detailed, as I don't know what you mean with "It doesent work"

Comment: Well the problem is, some of them work on styling of the carousel, but some of them dont change anything. By the way this is just another question. http://pastebin.com/Uwnk21G2

Comment: I need to wait 90 minutes before making new post, would be pretty happy if u helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following will require the HTML element to have the ID `myCarousel` as well as the classes defined above.

```
#myCarousel.carousel {
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 675px;
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

#myCarousel.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
  height: 350px;
}

#myCarousel.carousel .item {
  height: 675px;
  background-color: #777;
}
#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 675px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my mistake was leaving an empty space after #myCarousel, like #myCarousel .carousel :D

Comment: @Toeuwer3 Oh yeah makes sense. Yeah you want to make sure that you don't have that space otherwise it's like an OR not AND. Remember to up vote/accept the answer if it helped :)

Comment: Yeah it helped, but last line needed to have empty space after myCarousel

Comment: `#myCarousel.carousel-inner > .item > img` needed to be `#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .item > img`?